# Can I import my data sources from SQLDeveloper into Jetbrains Datagrip?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, datagrip

Is its possible to import my database sources (with or without passwords) into Jetbrains DataGrip from Oracle SQLDeveloper (on OSX)? Or if not is there another way, like export to a TNS file that could be consumed by Datagrip somehow? I just don't want to re-enter all of my configs, I work with a lot of databases.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5074

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000538024-Is-there-an-easy-way-to-import-DB-connections-from-SQLDeveloper-into-DataGrip-

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [sqldeveloper connections importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13103-sqldeveloper-connections-importer) plugin by akmal Sarhan that offers this functionality for all non-Community-Edition JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: It imported connections with Athena driver and I can't change them.